# Install Sql Server 2008 64 bit on Windows Server 2003 (X86) Service Pack 2

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003

Can anybody tell me Is it possible to install Install Sql Server 2008 64 bit on Windows Server 2003 (X86) Service Pack 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 64 bit OS can support 32 bit applications thanks to WoW (Windows on Windows, wow32.exe) but "older system" cannot support "newer system" if that makes sense. ie if cars have to maintain the same speed on a track, a fast car can go as slow as a slow car, but a slow car cannot go as fast as a fast car.
If the OS is the weakest link there's nothing you can do but upgrade (or use 32 bit SQL Server)